# с++ *** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c++, c

Я пытаюсь сравнить два элемента массива, текущий и предыдущий, ставлю break; чтобы закончить выполнение цикла и выводится такое сообщение в консоль - с++ *** stack smashing detected ***:  terminated Aborted (core dumped).

В чем проблема?

Код:

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[0];

    for(uint16_t i=0;;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Number ";
        cin>>array[i];
        cout<<endl;


        if (i!=0 && array[i]==array[i-1])
        {
            break;
        }


    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том что у вас массив нулевого размера. Т.е. в нем нет элементов к которым можно обратиться.

Comment: `int array[0];` вы создаете массив нулевого размера и туда вводите данные

Comment: C++ не разрешает создание массивов нулевого размера.

Comment: А как мне тогда указать размерность адекватно?

Comment: используйте `std::vector`